# Как обработать исключение RemoteJSDataStream NullReferenceException?

Tags: c#, blazor-server-side, .net-6

Я получаю сообщение об ошибке при параллельной загрузке файлов как StreamContent из .NET 6 / Blazor Server-Side в API через HttpClient. Вот сокращенный код и полный текст ошибки:

З.Ы. RemoteJSRuntime который передается для Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits.RemoteJSDataStream.ReceiveData фреймворком, имеет значение NULL, поэтому возникает ошибка. Однако почему передает NULL не понимаю. Отловить, погасить, как то повлиять пока не могу.

З.Ы.Ы. Это не связано с ApiClient, работает нормально. Ошибка возникает только при запуске после первой загрузки страницы, как ни странно, после повторной перезагрузки страницы и запуска все работает.

```cs
void StartUploadTask(List<IBrowserFile> files)
{
    foreach (var item in files)
    {
        Task t = taskFactory.StartNew(async () =>
        {
            await semaphoreSlim.WaitAsync();
            try
            {
                // .... prepare 

                await httpClient.PostAsync(url, formData, cancellationToken);
            }
            finally
            {
                semaphoreSlim.Release();
            }
        });

        tasks.Add(t);
    }
}
```

```json
blazor.server.js:1 [2021-12-06T19:07:53.123Z] Error: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits.RemoteJSDataStream.ReceiveData(RemoteJSRuntime runtime, Int64 streamId, Int64 chunkId, Byte[] chunk, String error)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.RendererSynchronizationContext.<>c__11`1.<<InvokeAsync>b__11_0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits.CircuitHost.ReceiveJSDataChunk(Int64 streamId, Int64 chunkId, Byte[] chunk, String error)
```

Comment: Пропадет ли ошибка, если `taskFactory.StartNew` заменить на `Task.Run`?

Comment: @aepot Заменил, но не пропало. Ошибка пропала после отката до .NET 5. Но это не решение.

Comment: Завел баг на всякий: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/38854